# Push Upgrade Failure - Ineligible Upgrades while trying to push upgrades to orgs

Tags: package, managed-package

Recently while trying to push upgrades to target orgs, all are failing on step 2.1.    Even when I spin up a new trial (Which comes in on our version 1.90) I can upgrade up until 2.1, then 2.2 fails.   (2.43 is our current version).   I was able to upgrade a version that was past 2.2, without issue from 2.42 to 2.43.    When I click on the target name, it just says "Ineligible Upgrade"  I've been told it could be an issue with Apex Classes, but why would it say Ineligible?     This has just started happening recently, and seems to coincide with when we merged two companies into one, but can't prove that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this with push upgrades before.  Usually, you can click on the individual record and get an exact error message about what's wrong.

The things I've seen trigger this before are:

- New metadata in the package references a RecordTypeId field on an object which has no record types in the target org.
- For extension packages, the packages being extended are not upgraded to the required version in the target org.

Generally, it means that there is some requirement in the version you are trying to push which is not met in the target org.  That could be referenced metadata or org level features which are not enabled, or probably a host of other things.  In my limited experience with these, the detailed error message provides enough information to figure out what requirement is not being met.